# Сравнение списка внутри списка в Python, Синтаксис python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть 2 списка - k и l. Список k содержит внутри себя еще один список.

```
k = [["дом", "cказка"]]
l = ["дом", "шуруповерт", "сказка"]
if k[0] in l:
    print("1")
else:
    print("0")
```

Дом и сказка хранятся в k и в l. Мне нужно, чтобы выдавало 1, но оно выводит 0. Как сделать подобное?

Comment: в 0 индексе лежит список, правильно будет `if k[0][0] in l:`

Comment: Спасибо большое